# How to make dots change color when they land in a box

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint
speed("fastest")

pendown()
goto(200, 0)
goto(200, 200)
goto(0, 200)
goto(0,0)
goto(200,200)


area_size = 800 
max_coord = area_size / 2

num_dots = 300 

setup(area_size, area_size)

for _ in range(num_dots):

    dots_pos_x = randint(-max_coord, max_coord)
    dots_pos_y = randint(-max_coord, max_coord);

if dots_pos_y > dots_pos_x and dots_pos_y <= 200:
    elif dots_pos_y <= dots_pos_x <= 200:
    else:

hideturtle()
done()
```

OK so this code draws a square with a line splitting it making two equal triangles, and then it generates 300 randomly places dots on the screen. What i REALLY want to know is how can i get the dots that land in ONE half of the square to turn red and when they land in the other half of the square i want them to turn blue. And the ones that don't land in the box stay black?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may try to use `points_inside_poly()` ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#test-whether-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon))

Comment: how would i use that in my code? im a python noob, and this has take me a long time to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that if your square was a rectangle, it would have these properties:

```
X = 0
Y = 0
Width = 200
Height = 200
```

And the line would consist of these two points:

```
A(0,0)
B(200,200)
```

Supposing that X,Y coordinates begin from the upper-left corner then:

```
if dots_pos_y > dots_pos_x and dots_pos_y <= 200:

     # Dot landed on the LOWER half of the square

elif dots_pos_y <= dots_pos_x and dots_pos_x <= 200:

     # Dot landed on the UPPER half of the square

else:
     # Dot DID NOT land on the square
```

Comment: Where would i add code to my current one? Thank you for your response.

Comment: under dots_pos_y = randint(-max_coord, max_coord)

Comment: Its not working it just spits out a invalid syntax error for the elif command. i must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Make proper indentation. Make sure variable names are correct

Comment: i have edited my questions could you please have a look if ive done it correctly.

Comment: the "elif" should be at the same column as "if". So does the "else:"

Comment: just tried that still an error

Comment: It seems to me that you are not capable enough of pulling this through. I don't mean to underestimate or discourage you, but you should take a look at some python tutorials first

Comment: The "if" statement should start at the same column as the command above it.

Comment: Try test out my code and see if it works for you.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The code should work on every machine

Comment: what i meant to ask was could you try it and see what is wrong and how to fix it so it does work.

Comment: This is something YOU should do. Otherwise, hire a programmer to do it ;)